# Squid 3.3 Transparent IPv4 and IPv6 Proxy with TPROXY

Tags: iptables, squid, centos-7, iproute2

I'm attempting to change my Squid transparent setup from using generic NAT that's limited to IPv4 only and switching it to TPROXY, for IPv6 support. I'm having difficulties getting transparent clients to work under the new setup however, all requests are met with squid throwing the following error on all requests:

"The requested URL could not be retrieved"

It would appear there is a routing issue somewhere but I'm not sure what's wrong.

I am using `iptables` and `ip6tables` on my DD-WRT router and Squid Proxy along with `iproute2` to do the routing parts on both sides.

By default, it appears the `ip6table_mangle` module is not loaded by default on DD-WRT, but was compiled into the build running on my router:

```
find /lib/modules -name "*.ko" | grep -i mangle
/lib/modules/3.10.89/ip6table_mangle.ko
```

Loaded the module and added to startup script for future boots:

```
insmod ip6table_mangle
```

**DD-WRT routing info:**

```
# Squid transparent proxy
PROXY_IPV4="192.168.x.x"
PROXY_IPV6="xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::x"
CLIENTIFACE=br0
FWMARK=3

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i $CLIENTIFACE -p tcp --dport 80 -s $PROXY_IPV4 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i $CLIENTIFACE -p tcp --dport 80 -s $PROXY_IPV6 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i $CLIENTIFACE -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark $FWMARK
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark $FWMARK -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i $CLIENTIFACE -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark $FWMARK
ip6tables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark $FWMARK -j ACCEPT

iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i $CLIENTIFACE -o $CLIENTIFACE -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -t filter -A FORWARD -i $CLIENTIFACE -o $CLIENTIFACE -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

ip rule add fwmark $FWMARK table 2
ip -6 rule add fwmark $FWMARK table 2
ip route add default via $PROXY_IPV4 table 2
ip -6 route add default via $PROXY_IPV6 table 2

# End Squid intercept proxy config
```

**Squid Proxy routing (on the server itself):**

```
iptables -F -t mangle
iptables -X -t mangle
ip6tables -F -t mangle
ip6tables -X -t mangle
iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
ip6tables -t mangle -N DIVERT

iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 3129

ip6tables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1
ip6tables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
ip6tables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 3129

ip -f inet rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip -f inet route add local default dev eno1 table 100

ip -f inet6 rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip -f inet6 route add local default dev eno1 table 100
```

**squid conf:**

```
http_port 3129 tproxy
```

**sysctl config:**

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eno1.rp_filter = 0
```

`eno1` is the main ethernet interface I have also tried using `lo` without any success.

The traffic is being passed to the Squid box, so it appears the router is doing its job. Its when the traffic ends up at Squid box where it appears to be going wrong. All requests are being logged but returning 500 errors.

As far as I am aware my setup supports TPROXY:

- CentOS 7
- Squid 3.3.8 (EPEL)
- iptables/ip6tables 1.4.21
- Linux Kernel 3.10
- libcap 2.22

I've used these sources as guidance, but can't get a working setup.

- http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/IptablesPolicyRoute
- http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Tproxy4#Feature:_TPROXY_version_4.1.2B-_Support

Any advice on what might be the issue or to debug further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out everything was correctly setup. What the actual problem was is my cache_peer directive for Privoxy. The error thrown is actually Squid saying it can't hand off the traffic to Privoxy. This is because the tproxy setup is confusing it.

In order to avoid it you have to add `no-tproxy` to the cache_peer line

```
cache_peer hostname parent 8118 7 no-tproxy ...
```